# What does Sfdc.canvas() do?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am going through `Force.com Canvas Developer's Guide` and I see the function `Sfdc.canvas()` used many places but it is not mentioned what it does exactly..Can someone give your input? For example, I see the code and not sure what the `Sfdc.canvas()` is doing.Thanks.

```
Sfdc.canvas(function() {        
    var login = Sfdc.canvas.byId("login"),
    loggedIn = Sfdc.canvas.oauth.loggedin(),
    token = Sfdc.canvas.oauth.token()
    login.innerHTML = (loggedIn) ? "Logout" : "Login";
    if (loggedIn) {
    // Only displaying part of the OAuth token for better formatting.
    Sfdc.canvas.byId("oauth").innerHTML = Sfdc.canvas.oauth.token()
    .substring(1,40) + "…";
    }
    login.onclick=loginHandler;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function passed to Sfdc.canvas runs when the dom is ready. In this case it:

- Grabs the element with the id "login"
- Gets the current oauth state
- Grabs the current token
- Sets the "login" element to either say "Login" or "Logout"
- If it is logged in, it prints the first 40 char of the oauth token
- It attaches the login handler to the "login" element's onClick

Long story short, it is a convenience method for onready.

Source: [A comment in this example, near line 31](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/Content/canvas_app_oauth_code_example.htm)